# I cannot see the armature in any mode and I pressed all the H buttons

Tags: armature, bones, rigify

I am super new to blender. I made a person in MakeHuman and then imported it to blender. I made hair on it and then I went to add the armature and its not showing up. I can make one and see it in a different file but I cant see it in the file with my character. I flipped through all the modes, I see the armature is present in the outline. I pressed all the H variations, I clicked as many buttons that looked relevant as I could. I restarted the program and the computer. I'm very lost and I would very much like to not have to remake this. Please help. Thank you!

Edit: I can see it in the shading tab but not the sculpting tab. but I can t manipulate it here. Why?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You've done good so far in trying to troubleshoot this.  Maybe you could upload a file so people could figure out exactly what's going on with your armature?

Comment: Many imported models are 100 times bigger. May be the rig is very small compare to the mesh. Select the rig in the outliner, then hover the cursor back to the 3D view and press numpad del to focus on it.

Comment: I pressed del to zoom in on it and it still didn't show up. I tried to scale it bigger and then zoom in and I still don't see it. and I flipped through all the modes just in case.

Comment: @Nathan I dont see an option for that on here?

Comment: People here typically use https://blend-exchange.com/ to host files, and then copy/paste the provided markup into their questions.

Comment: Hold on. I can see it in the shading tab. but I don't know how to manipulate it here